# CustomAction in c# via wix 3.7 fails with error code 1154

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action

I've created a custom action to uninstall VS Package when choosing 'Remove' on Wix setup.

```
 public class CustomActions
{

    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
    {
        ActionResult result = ActionResult.Failure;

        try
        {
            session.Log("Begin CustomAction1");



            string VSIXInstallerPath = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config", "VSIXInstallerLocation", null);
            Process UninstallVSPackage = new Process();

            UninstallVSPackage = Process.Start(VSIXInstallerPath, "/u:GUID /quiet");

            result = ActionResult.Success;

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            session.Log("ERROR in custom action  {0}",
                    ex.ToString());
            return ActionResult.Failure;


        }

        return result;

    }
}
}
```

This is the relevant WIX markup:

```
 <Binary Id="UninstallVSPackageAction"
        src="$(var.TargetDir)\SELA.TFS.MBWI.CustomAction1.CA.dll" />

<CustomAction Id="RemoveVsPackage" BinaryKey="UninstallVSPackageAction"
 DllEntry="DeleteVSPackage" Execute="deferred" Return="check" />


  <Custom Action="RemoveVsPackage" After="InstallInitialize">
        Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE
      </Custom>
```

This fails with the next error log:

```
CustomAction RemoveVsPackage returned actual error code 1154 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (s) (F8:60) [06:43:39:304]: Note: 1: 1723 2: RemoveVsPackage 3: DeleteVSPackage 4: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI1663.tmp 
MSI (s) (F8:60) [06:43:39:304]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (F8:60) [06:43:39:304]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1723 
Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action RemoveVsPackage, entry: DeleteVSPackage, library: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI1663.tmp 
MSI (s) (F8:60) [06:43:41:476]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (F8:60) [06:43:41:476]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (s) (F8:60) [06:43:41:476]: Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action RemoveVsPackage, entry: DeleteVSPackage, library: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI1663.tmp
```

Comment: No. This is not the case. In this post the author is referring to the custom action assembly instead to the actual custom action dll. T

Comment: Are you sure `src="$(var.TargetDir)` is correct?

Comment: Well. I've edited the source for the post. It's actually  src="$(var.SELA.TFS.MBWI.CustomAction1.TargetDir)\SELA.TFS.MBWI.CustomAction1.CA.dll" The dll is located in the Release dir.

Comment: When logging, does the `session.Log("Begin CustomAction1");` log correctly, or does it fall over before then? I'd also check if $(var.SELA.TFS.MBWI.CustomAction1.TargetDir) actually gives you the directory you expect (I personally just use relative paths)

Comment: APPEND: 
As of: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/votive_project_references.htm : 
`$(var.MyProject.TargetDir)` points to:
`C:\users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject\bin\Debug\`
You might want to check your project references, too.

Comment: I've changed the source directly to the Release CA Dll using absolute path and added MessageBox.Show(""); on both try..catch. It looks like it fails before and something is wrong with the product.wxs. Can't really point what the root of this error.

Comment: I'd keep trying to get a text box to show (or, even just `session.Log("Hello World!");`) to try and find at what exact point does your installer fall over. If you can't seem to change anything then the problem is likely with your build process, if you can get a dummy CA to fire just before this one, then you might need to look at how you are embedding your resources (Votive is meant to do that for you, but I personally just store any passed data and then call a c# project from any managed CA, it's easier to test.)